# create a matrix of objects with x y coordinates within arrays in vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm trying to create a matrix of objects with x, y coordinates.

For example:

```js
var simpleMatrix = [
    [{x: 0, y: 0}, {x: 0, y: 1}],
    [{x: 1, y: 0}, {x: 1, y: 1}],
]

console.log('simpleMatrix is: ', simpleMatrix)
```

How do I abstract this into a function so I can generate a bigger grid? For example, a grid with 10 rows by 10 columns (or 5 rows by 6 columns, or whatever).

I want an array of objects that each contain their own coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can chain two `Array.from`s together to build nested arrays from scratch:

```js
const makeMatrix = (lengthX, lengthY) => (
  Array.from(
    { length: lengthY }, (_, y) => Array.from(
      { length: lengthX }, (_, x) => ({ x, y })
    )
  )
);
console.log(makeMatrix(2, 2));
console.log(makeMatrix(3, 1));
```

The first argument to `Array.from` is an object that the interpreter attempts to turn into an array. Passing an object with a `length` property will create an array of that length with `undefined` values. Then, the second argument to `Array.from` is an optional mapping function, the same as `Array.prototype.map` - here, we can exploit that by using the second argument to `.map`, which is the current index being iterated over.

So, with the outer `Array.from`'s getting the `y` coordinate from the mapper, and the inner `Array.from` getting the `x` coordinate from the mapper, we can then return an object with the desired coordinates from the inner function, which will create the grid.

Comment: That is beautiful, but would you be able to explain how it works so that we can learn from the answer? :)

Comment: agreed, explanation would be great!

Comment: note I switch the y and x to make it match my original example: `const makeMatrix = (x, y) => (
  Array.from(
    { length: x }, (_, x) => Array.from(
      { length: y }, (_, y) => ({ x, y })
    )
  )
);
console.log(makeMatrix(2, 2));`

Answer (score 0):

```
var inputCoord = [];
var matrix;

function initMatrix( rows, cols ) {

    var index = 0;
    var aMatrix = [];
    for( var x = 0; x < rows; x++ ) {

        var aRow = [];
        for( var y = index; y < inputCoord.length; y++ ) {

            aCol.push( inputCoord[ y ] );

            if( y == ( cols - 1 ) ) {
                index += cols;
                break;
            }
        }

        aMatrix.push( aRow );

    }

    return aMatrix;

}

inputCoord.push( { x: 0, y: 1 } );
inputCoord.push( { x: 0, y: 1 } );
inputCoord.push( { x: 0, y: 1 } );
inputCoord.push( { x: 0, y: 1 } );
inputCoord.push( { x: 0, y: 1 } );  
inputCoord.push( { x: 0, y: 1 } );

matrix = initMatrix( 2, 3 ); //rows * cols have to always be equal to inputCoord.length
```

I didn't try the code, but something like this should work.